# Can you set a default value for a javascript function argument that is only used if the argument is not passed at all?

Tags: javascript

so say you've got

```
var fun = function({foo='bar'}={}){
    console.log(foo)
}
```

It will output

```
fun()
// 'bar'
fun({foo: 'woo'})
// 'woo'
fun({foo: undefined})
// 'bar'
```

but, what if you only want to use the default value when the argument wasn't passed at all, so even if it was passed as undefined, it is used as undefined

```
fun({foo: undefined})
// undefined
```

Just wondering

Comment: `undefined` is falsy value in JS. You can pass undefined as string `fun({foo: 'undefined'})`

Comment: I don't think it's the best idea to set all your undefined variables to a string 'undefined'

Comment: Did you need to use the default value when the argument is equal to null or undefined ?

Answer (score 2):

ES6 supports default arguments

```js
const fun = function(obj = {foo: 'bar'}) {
    console.log(obj.foo);
};

fun();
fun({foo: 'woo'});
fun({foo: undefined});
```

Or you can define the behavior with missed argument by yourself

```js
var fun = function(obj) {
    if(obj === undefined) {
        obj = {foo: 'bar'};
    }

    console.log(obj.foo);
};

fun();
fun({foo: 'woo'});
fun({foo: undefined});
```

Comment: interestinggggg, very interesting, is there anyway to get this behaviour with going `obj = {foo:'bar'}` ? so you don't have to access the arguments by `obj.` in the function scope?

Answer (score 0):

Not the prettiest, but gets the job done with a small amount of code:

```
function foo(a=(()=>(arguments.length>0 ? undefined : 'bar'))()){
    console.log(a)
}

foo('something') // 'something'
foo(undefined)  // undefined
foo(null)  // null
foo() // bar
```

This won't work with an arrow function on the outside, or a non-arrow function on the inside, because of how `arguments` works. Arrow functions don't create their own `arguments` list, and the inside arrow function inherits it as a local variable.

Default function parameters will be used when passing undefined, but other falsey values such as null will retain the original value, which is why null worked as expected in this example.

I think this approach is acceptable for 1 optional parameter at the end of the list. If they're inside the list, this approach will fail hard (because `arguments.length` will no longer be decisive), and you'll have to check for and re-assign the desired value in the function body.

Answer (score 0):

There is no shortcut for the last case `fun({foo: undefined})`.

```js
function f( { a } = { a: 1 } ) { 
  if ( a === void 0 ) a = 3
  console.log( a ) 
}

f()
f( undefined )
f( { a: 2 } )
f( { a: undefined } )
```

or

```js
function f( { a } = { a: 1 } ) { 
  (function( b = 3 ) {
    console.log( b )
  })(a)
}

f()
f( undefined )
f( { a: 2 } )
f( { a: undefined } )
```